# Create multiple Checkboxes with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I want to create multiple checkboxes with JavaScript. I tried the following:

```
var response= data;
        var container = document.createElement('div');
        var checkboxContainer = document.createElement('div');
        checkboxContainer.setAttribute('class', 'checkbox');
        var label;
        var checkBox;

        for(i=0;i<response.length;i++){
            label = document.createElement('label');
            checkBox = document.createElement('input');
            checkBox.type = "checkbox";
            checkBox.name = "selDates[]";
            checkBox.value = response[i]['date'];

            label.innerHTML = response[i]['date'] + " " + response[i]['typ'];
            label.appendChild(checkBox);

            checkboxContainer.appendChild(label);
            container.appendChild(checkboxContainer);
        }
        $("#downloadContent").prepend(container);
```

As I can see in the chrome developer tools it creates all my checkboxes, but only display one. All labels are displayed.

[image]

As you can see, one checkbox is displayed with all (3) labels.

[image]

Here you can see a print screen of the code.

Why is there just one checkbox displayed? For your information, I use Bootstrap 3 and jQuery.

Thanks for your help!

Yanick

Comment: can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)...? and post the content inside `checkbox` css?

Comment: does your class `checkbox` or any other css style do anything to hide the other checkboxes?

Comment: Have you seen that the checkbox is shown before the text and should be shown after it? You probably have a CSS issue.

Comment: Well, to test this I've set the Bootstrap label class "checkbox-inline" but I get the same result. I am currently working on a fiddle for you guys.. 
@Moloo Salsas: Yes I've seen this. It's correct

Comment: As I've said, if it is correct, you probably have a CSS issue. Try disabling CSS to see if it works right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Javascript seems ok (except may be for adding `checkboxContainer` every time in the loop).

One possibility is that CSS makes the other checkboxes not visible.

For example the style for those `label`s could be defined with `position:absolute` (thus all of them are visible, but one above the other), or `display:none` except for one...

Hard to tell for sure without a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: This is not an answer at all. Should be a comment.

Comment: @ManoloSalsas: I think it's an answer (CSS is the reason the other checkboxes are not visible). Of course without a reproducible example I cannot be 100% sure.

Comment: well if I set display:none to my labels nothing is displayed, because the checkboxes are in the label tag...

Comment: @Yanick: CSS can select specific elements (for example `:first-child`)

Comment: You were right, after add add a <br> after every label, the are now displayed... thx allot. Is there any "nicer" way than a <br> after every label to solve this?